# Can't seem to declare a function no matter how I edit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I'm trying to implement category filtering of Isotope items in a Wordpress theme I built.
I've got everything working and ready except this one function that I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for **mycontainer**.
I have tried rewriting it every way I can think of but I'm getting the same results. I have a plugin that, among other things, does something similar and it works fine. So, I know it can be done. I looked at the plugin's code but it is combined with so much other code that I cannot decipher it and the plugin cannot remain on the site.

```
(function () {
    jQuery(document);

    var mycontainer = jQuery("#isotope-container");
    mycontainer.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".item",
        layoutMode: "fitRows"
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    jQuery("#options a").click(function(){
        var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-filter");
        mycontainer.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: if `jQuery("#isotope-container")` does not exist, you will get undefined assigned to `mycontainer` in which case failures are bound to happen.  Are you sure the element is found in the page?  Also, `.isotope` does not seem to be defined as a function

Comment: @blurfus that's not true , `$(selector)` always creates a jQuery object regardless if selector is found or not and method chained to it will fail quietly if a collection of elements doesn't exist

Comment: isotope is not a function http://jsfiddle.net/8xack/ - code works fine when it is and the wrapper is corrected.

Comment: Yes, the element is in the page.

Comment: It's not isotope, `$` is not defined. You're trying to execute before jQuery is loaded.